# Passing extra props to component wrapped in FieldArray (React)

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-props

I have a redux form inside which, amongst other things, I have a `FieldArray`.
I am passing an array as `name` and pointing to a component, defined outside the body of the class, as `component`. Very simplified:

```
...
return(
   <>
      <FieldArray name={myArray} component={emails}/>
   </>
)
...
```

this is `emails`

```
const emails = ({ fields }) => (
    <>
        <Table>
            <Table.Body>
                {fields.map((code, index) => (
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>
                            <Field
                                name={code}
                                type="text"
                                component={customInput}
                                autoFocus
                            />
                        </Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>
                            <Button content='XXXXX'/>
                        </Table.Cell>

                    </Table.Row>
                ))}
            </Table.Body>
          </Table>
        <Button content='XXXXX' />
    </>
);
```

What I would like to be able to do is to pass a dictionary to 'emails' in order to populate the 'content' field of the buttons (where XXXXX is now), as they come from a translation file.

Now, looking at the [documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/fieldarray.md/), I can see they mention a 'props' parameter. I tried something on the line:

```
<FieldArray name={myArray} component={emails} props={myDictionary}/>
```

But I do not seem able to actually pass anything to FieldArray (or at least to retrieve it on the other side).
I have seen a few existing questions, but the focus seem a bit different.

Does anyone have experience with it or any suggestion? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create functional component with react your component accepts props as an argument.

For example this piece of code is:

```
const emails = ({ fields }) => {
    // do something with fields
    return <div></div>
}
```

Is equavalent of:

```
const emails = (props) => {
    const {fields} = props;
    // do something with fields
    return <div></div>
}
```

Therefore if you pass it like

```
<FieldArray name={myArray} component={emails} myDictionary={myDictionary}/>
```

You will be able to access it like so:

```
const FieldArray = (props) =>{
    const {myDictionary} = props;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass object to `props` which will be merged with props of `emails` component, so if you want to get it with `myDictionary` named prop you need to pass an object like this

```
props={{ myDictionary: { test: 'test' } }}
```

and you will get

```
const emails = ({ fields, myDictionary }) => (
```

something like this:

```
return(
   <>
      <FieldArray name={myArray} component={emails} props={{ myDictionary: myDictionary }} />
   </>
)

const emails = ({ fields, myDictionary }) => (
    <>
        <Table>
            <Table.Body>
                {fields.map((code, index) => (
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.Cell>
                            <Field
                                name={code}
                                type="text"
                                component={customInput}
                                autoFocus
                            />
                        </Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>
                            <Button content={myDictionary.test}/>
                        </Table.Cell>

                    </Table.Row>
                ))}
            </Table.Body>
          </Table>
        <Button content={myDictionary.test} />
    </>
);
```